# iReport 5.1.0 on OSX is missing "Option" menu item (Tools -> Option)

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Just installed iReport 5.1.0 on OSX Yosemite and the Option menu in Tools->Option is missing.

I have to setup the fonts....but where?

Comment: what is the jdk version you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu is under Preferences.

[image: Preferences]
[image]

**UPDATE**

iReport 5.1.0 doesn't work well with JDK1.7 or later. Set it to 1.6.

To change the jdk path open ireport.conf and set it to similar like below,

```
jdkhome="/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Comment: I have no preferences menu under iReport.
Only:
About
Services
Hide iReport
Hide Others
Show All
Quit iReport

Comment: what is the jdk version you are using?

Comment: was jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home"
changed to jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_65-b14-462.jdk/Contents/Home"

but nothing change on the menu

Comment: The menu is disappearing because of jdk only. You have to use one which is opt.

Comment: its a jdk + ireport issue, that is why you are not getting any menus in ireport, you have to use lower build releases for jdk or you have to use iReport 5.6.0 or any newer version if available